# Display normal price or variable price range in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I've a list of products and I've a problem about displaying the range of prices in variable products.

As you can see if the price is a normal price everything works. Nevertheless if the product has a variable price the price displayed is 0€

Well, the code for displaying price is this:

```
<?php
if (isset($ebookstore_theme_option['woo-list-price']) && 
    $ebookstore_theme_option['woo-list-price'] == 'enable') {
    $ebookstore_woo .= '<strong class="amount">'.esc_attr($currency).''.$price_sale.'</strong>';
}
```

Any idea about how to display the variable range price?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a variable product in WooCommerce you need:

- to target variable product type
- to get the min and the max prices.

So you should need to get an instance of the product object. In general you can get it with:

```
 global $product;
```

If it doesn't work you will use intead:

```
global $post;
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
```

Now from this point you will use the following:

```
<?php
global $product;

if ( isset( $ebookstore_theme_option['woo-list-price'] ) && $ebookstore_theme_option['woo-list-price'] == 'enable' ){

    // For all product types that are not "variable products"
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
        $ebookstore_woo .= '<strong class="amount">'.esc_attr($currency).''.$price_sale.'</strong>';
    }
    // For variable products    
    else {
        $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min' );
        $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max' );

        $ebookstore_woo .= '<strong class="amount">'.esc_attr($currency).''.$min_price.' - '.esc_attr($currency).''.$max_price.'</strong>';
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the [`WC_Product_Variable` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html)

---

May be you don't know, but woocommerce has several formatting price functions as:

- `wc_price( $price );`
- `wc_format_price_range( $from, $to );`
- `wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price, $sale_price );`

They will all include the currency